# How to check if file is being copied under macOS

Tags: macos, file, fuser

Users on our network copy files on the server in a directory called "DropBox" with AFP connection, simply dragging them with the Finder.

A script running on the server checks periodically for the presence of new files inside "DropBox" and then moves them with **mv** into other directories.

How can the script check if a file is being copied (and wait for the process to complete before moving it away)?

I've tried with **fuser *filename*** with no success.  If the file copy is issued by a remote machine **fuser** reports that no process is using the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to this problem:

#### 1. flag the filename to tell the file is partial:

When a file is written (moved/copied) into the DropBox `.part` extension is added to the name. When the writing is over the `.part` extension is removed.
Other processes operate on files only if the `.part` extension is **not** present.

#### 2. check the file size; if it's constant then the write operation is ended *(maybe)*

This is less accurate and more complicated that (1) but offer a good guess if option 1 is not viable for whatever reason.
For each file in the dropbox the time the size isn't changed is recorded.
When a file increases in size the time value is reset to zero.
When a file is not being written the time values remains constant.
If a file isn't grown for at least (30 seconds, 1 minute, the more time you can afford the better it is of course) then write operation are over and the file can be managed.
This approach fails when a transfer in interrupted.